# Alignment issues with dynamically filled table having a fixed header line (timing issue)

Tags: java, android, tableview, dynamic

I'm trying to dynamically build a table that has a fixed header line. The build takes data from the network, so it is run from a Task. The problem is the following:

*If the task takes longer than a certain amount of time, then the header alignment code does not work properly.*

Look at the thread.sleep call. If the value is greater than 0 the header line will not be aligned, otherwise works as expected.

I have run out of ideas. Tried *requestLayout(), invalidate(), forceLayout()* on the root view and everywhere else I could think of.

Any idea?

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:keepScreenOn="true">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bodyheader"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="X"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Y"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/header">
    <hu.dwim.test.TableView android:id="@+id/bodytable"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code for the TableView class that tries to keep its header aligned:

```
package hu.dwim.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TableView extends TableLayout {
private LinearLayout header;

public TableView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public LinearLayout getHeader() {
    return header;
}

public void setHeader(LinearLayout header) {
    this.header = header;
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    TableRow firstRow = getChildCount() > 0 ? (TableRow)getChildAt(0) : null;
    if (firstRow != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < header.getChildCount(); i++) {
            TextView textView = (TextView)header.getChildAt(i);
            textView.setWidth(firstRow.getChildAt(i).getWidth());
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is the code for the activity and the task:

```
package hu.dwim.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
private TableView tableView;

private class FillTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        tableView.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(TestActivity.this);
            TextView textView = new TextView(TestActivity.this);
            textView.setText("Hello world");
            tableRow.addView(textView);
            textView = new TextView(TestActivity.this);
            textView.setText("Shouldn't this work");
            tableRow.addView(textView);
            tableView.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tableView = (TableView)findViewById(R.id.bodytable);
    tableView.setHeader((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bodyheader));
    tableView.removeAllViews();
    new FillTask().execute(null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I finally found the answer just after posting the question... :(

The code that is updating the header should be run from a new Handler().post(new Runnable() ...

don't know why